# Reenable Spotlight

Tags: catalina, spotlight

I noticed that spotlight was using a lot of CPU and I did not have time to debug it, so I disabled spotlight with this command:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

Now I want to reenable spotlight and debug why it is non-stop indexing my drive, but I can't figure out how to reenable it.

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist: service already loaded
```

But when I search for anything I get "No Results".

Here is my configuration:

[image: Spotlight System Preferences - Search Results]
[image: Spotlight System Preferences - Privacy]

How do I get indexing reenable?

[EDIT]

I tried one of the suggested answers with this result:

```
 % sudo mdutil -a -i off
Password:
/:
2020-09-03 15:35:44.980 mdutil[33360:1381738] mdutil disabling Spotlight: / -> kMDConfigSearchLevelFSSearchOnly
    Indexing disabled.
/System/Volumes/Data:
2020-09-03 15:35:45.026 mdutil[33360:1381738] mdutil disabling Spotlight: /System/Volumes/Data -> kMDConfigSearchLevelFSSearchOnly
    Indexing disabled.
/Volumes/MBP15 Time Machine:
2020-09-03 15:35:45.060 mdutil[33360:1381738] mdutil disabling Spotlight: /Volumes/MBP15 Time Machine -> kMDConfigSearchLevelFSSearchOnly
    Indexing enabled. (Indexing level may not be changed on volumes which have a Time Machine backup)
/Volumes/MBP15 Time Machine/Backups.backupdb:
2020-09-03 15:35:49.728 mdutil[33360:1381738] mdutil disabling Spotlight: /Volumes/MBP15 Time Machine/Backups.backupdb -> kMDConfigSearchLevelFSSearchOnly
    Indexing enabled.
 % sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged
 % sudo mdutil -a -i on
/:
    Indexing enabled.
/System/Volumes/Data:
    Indexing enabled.
/Volumes/MBP15 Time Machine:
    Indexing enabled.
/Volumes/MBP15 Time Machine/Backups.backupdb:
    Indexing enabled.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open **Terminal** window from LaunchPad.

**First, turn off Spotlight:**

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
```

Next, **unload the metadata file that controls Spotlight’s index**:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

**Use the following command to re-loads the index :**

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

As a last step, **turn Spotlight back on**:

```
sudo mdutil -a -i on
```

After a few minutes to rebuild the index, Spotlight should be functioning as normal.

Comment: This worked but I think only the last command is necessary.  The `sudo launchctl unload` failed for me as Operation not permissed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the above problem on Catalina 10.15.7.  I don't use iCloud.  Turned on WireShark and ran `sudo mdutil -avi on` and noticed that there was activity with gateway.icloud.com.

I added the following line to my /etc/hosts file.

`127.0.0.1    gateway.icloud.com`

This effectively blocks/re-routes all traffic to that site locally.  This immediately fixed the re-indexing problem for me.

Those that use iCloud may want to comment out that line after indexing works again, for me, I'll leave it like that.